# How can I create a shortcut that works with or without a folder selected?

Tags: macos, automator, shortcut

I have a shell script that I'd like to be able to run from a keyboard shortcut.

- I want a single shortcut (let's say `^⌘K`) to invoke this script.
- If I'm in Finder and a folder is selected, I want it to pass the folder to the script.
- If I'm *not* in Finder, or I'm in Finder but a folder is not selected, I'd like it to run the script with no parameters.

Here's what I've tried:

### First attempt

In Automator, I created a new "Quick Action" and put a "Run Shell Script" block in it containing my script, and set "Workflow receives" to "folders" in "any application". (The script uses `"$@"` to receive the folder paths.)

In System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Services I then set a shortcut on this action to `^⌘K`.

**This only worked if a folder was selected.**

### Second attempt

I then changed "Workflow receives" to "no input" in "any application", and made sure the shortcut was set to `^⌘K`.

This runs the script anywhere, **but if a folder is selected, it doesn't get passed to the script**.

### Third attempt

I then changed duplicated the workflow, and set one to "Workflow receives no input in any application" and the other to "Workflow receives folder in any application". I then set the shortcut to `^⌘K` for both actions.

This behaves exactly like the second attempt: it runs the script anywhere, **but if a folder is selected, it doesn't get passed to the script**. It seems that having a "no input" workflow bound to the same shortcut prevents the "folders" workflow from running. (I was hoping that it would be reversed -- that the "folders" workflow would take precedence.)

### Additional testing

As a variation on attempt 3, I set the "no input" action to `^⌘K`, and the "folder" action to `⇧^⌘K`. This worked "correctly", in that `^⌘K` works anywhere, and `⇧^⌘K` works when I select a folder and passes the folders to the script. However, **I do not want to have separate shortcuts**. I want the same shortcut to do the right thing depending on context.

How can I have a single shortcut (eg: `^⌘K`) pass folders if they are selected, and otherwise pass no arguments, to a shell script?

Comment: Perhaps add actions to #2 to get the Finder selection and filter for folders?

Comment: @red_menace Interesting... how can I do that?

Comment: Just create your second Quick Action, but add a **Get Selected Finder Items** action at the beginning, followed by a **Filter Finder Items** for folders or whatever.  If nothing is selected, no result will be passed.

Comment: You can solve this with user interface commands, ignoring input. If the folder is selected, you just send a keystroke, like "Command+C" and get the folder info (with the full path and everything) from the clipboard during runtime. This article will help you https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes